# Report on Contacts over 40 years old / which filter?

Tags: reporting, filters

I was asked to create a report showing contacts and one of the filters requested is only contacts who are over 40 years old. The contacts have a Birthdate field.

In the report filter, I can't figure out how to set this criteria. Should I use a relative date? I've tried using the date 40 years from now but I realize this won't be valid in a year's time, for example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do some date math where you can do something like:

```
YEAR(Contact.Birthdate) <= YEAR(TODAY())-40
```

This is purely going to be based off year and not the actual month day, but this will get you close

Comment: You are suggesting a formula field on Contact?

Comment: Either that which evaluates to a boolean formula field, or, I thought you can do the same thing on a report as well?

Comment: see this [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GddgiUAB/filter-on-custom-report-formula) - reports can compare one field against another  but unless I'm mistaken, can't do field compares against a row level formula field

Comment: Someone recommended me to create a formula field on Contact (not visible on the page layout) like this: IF( NOT( ISBLANK( Birthdate ) ) ,
IF( DATE( 2000 , MONTH( Birthdate ) , DAY( Birthdate ) ) <= DATE( 2000 , MONTH( TODAY() ) , DAY( TODAY() ) ),
 YEAR (Today()) - YEAR ( Birthdate ),
YEAR (Today()) - YEAR ( Birthdate ) -1 ),
 null)    and then filter this field in the report filters Age >=40 and it works.